# work with fractions - Java NumberFormat pattern

Tags: java, javascript, dojo, fractions

I am using dojo, and i read this framework uses the Java NumberFormat pattern.

My question is:how to maintain the values of slider with fractions, and not the division. For example, 1/3 and not 0.333333333. This is because, in future i need to invert 1/3 to 3/1.

So the issue is, how maintain the value in fraction.

```
var theSlider = new dijit.form.HorizontalSlider({
                value:5,
                onChange: function(){
                    console.log(arguments);
                },
                name:"input"+[i],
                slideDuration:0,
                onChange:function(val){ dojo.byId('value'+[i]).value = dojo.number.format(1/val,{places:4})},
                minimum:1,
                maximum:9,
                discreteValues:9,
                style:{width:"400px"}
            },node);
```

Comment: The Java NumberFormat pattern allows you to format a number like `1033.33333` to be displayed as `1,033.33`. You want to display `0.333` as `1/3`. This cannot be done by the Java NumberFormat pattern.

Comment: well, I just want to avoid the division and add 1/ to all numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply:

```
onChange:function(val){ dojo.byId('value'+[i]).value = "1/" + val;},
```

Solved, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you want to create your own fraction class or find one on the web like:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/87241-fraction-class-that-does-the-4-main-calculation-functions/